# SwiftUI how to make tappable row and animate text visibility?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The code below gives me this:

[image]

Tapping the text or arrow rotates the arrow and shows the items. However I can't tap in the blank space between the text and the image. How can I tap the space area for this to work? Also, the text shows/hides the items instantaneously. Is there a way to toggle the showList state only after the animation is complete?

```
public struct Picker: View {
     @State private var showList = false
     private var iconAngle: Double {
          return showList ? 90 : 0
     }
     private let prompt: String

     public init(promptLocalizationKey: String) {
          self.prompt = NSLocalizedString(promptLocalizationKey, comment: "")
     }

     public var body: some View {
          let tap = TapGesture()
          .onEnded { _ in
                self.showList.toggle()
          }

          return
                VStack {
                     HStack {
                          Text(prompt)
                          Spacer()
                          Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.iconAngle))
                                .animation(.linear)
                     }.gesture(tap)
                     if showList {
                          Text("list item 1")
                          Text("list item 2")
                          Text("list item 3")
                     }
                }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs you might choose which way of transitioning the two animated UI elements can be better suited for your needs.

**1) To add an animation through your state changes** you just wrap `self.showList.toggle()` within `withAnimation()` **and to make the hole row or `HStack` tappable**, you treat it as a Rectangle content shape, check this code out.

**This animates `both` the text and arrow rotation together `at the same moment` with a smooth controlled visual effect:**

```
public struct Picker: View {
     @State private var showList = false
     private var iconAngle: Double {
          return showList ? 90 : 0
     }
     private let prompt: String

     public init(promptLocalizationKey: String) {
          self.prompt = NSLocalizedString(promptLocalizationKey, comment: "")
     }

     public var body: some View {
          let tap = TapGesture()
          .onEnded { _ in
            withAnimation() {
                self.showList.toggle()
            }
          }

          return
                VStack {
                     HStack {
                          Text(prompt)
                          Spacer()
                          Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.iconAngle))
                                .animation(.linear)
                     }
                     .contentShape(Rectangle())
                     .gesture(tap)

                    if showList {
                        Text("list item 1")
                        Text("list item 2")
                        Text("list item 3")
                    }
                }
     }
}
```

This should be a sample output:

[image]

**2) To animate text visibility `after` arrow rotation animation through `transition`**, thanks @eduardo for giving another viewpoint on this:

```
struct Picker: View {
    @State private var showList = false
    private var iconAngle: Double {
        return showList ? 90 : 0
    }
    private let prompt: String
    public init(promptLocalizationKey: String) {
        self.prompt = NSLocalizedString(promptLocalizationKey, comment: "")
    }
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(prompt)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.iconAngle))
                    .animation(.linear)
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(TapGesture()
            .onEnded { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    self.showList.toggle()
                }
            })
            if showList {
                VStack {
                    Text("list item 1")
                    Text("list item 2")
                    Text("list item 3")
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition
                .opacity
                .animation(Animation.linear.delay(0.5)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]